# Trouble joining two meshes together

Tags: mesh, modifiers

So, I'm trying to make a model of the lamp from the Simpsons. This top part is giving me trouble

[image]

At first it was easy I just booleaned a sphere to a cylander cylinder and they fit together perfectly.
[image]

When I tried adding the other cylinder, it looked pretty okay but I know that it could be better. I see this dimples and pinches around where the cylinder and sphere meet.

[image]
[image]

The geometry is pretty messed up and I was wondering if I am stuck just editing the vertices one by one, or if I'm going about this the wrong was and there is an easier way?

Comment: Don't boolean thing if your gonna modified it later as that joint show. If you care about the mesh topology, then don't even thinking about using boolean on complicate mesh (not cube)

Comment: as the picture show, I would create a plane first and extrude one side of the edges and make it adopt the shape and solidify it to make it like a tube

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to:

- Begin with a cube that you subdivide twice (smooth mode).
- Cut off a hole on the bottom, select the hole, flatten it on the Z axis (<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>.
- Make it a circle <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>.
- Extrude down to make the vertical cylinder.
- Do the exact same operation for the horizontal extrusion.
- Add some edge loops close to the edges you want to sharp.

[image]